# How invisible valueAxis/CategoryAxis in Amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How invisible valueAxis/CategoryAxis in Amcharts 4
[Amcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPNxL.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some code you are working at, or create a code pen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `axis.visible` property ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#visible_property)). Setting this property to `false` will hide the axis.

```
categoryAxis.visible = false;
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYgrwd) I created a working example.